# Transform a label from string to float

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I want to transform the label (that is a string) in a float number.
I'm doing like this:

```
label = LabelEncoder()
balanced_data['label'] = label.fit_transform(balanced_data['activity'])
balanced_data.head()
```

And I obtain label in number form but still string.
How can I fix it? Thank you
[image: This is the code]

Comment: Label encoding produces a string. Checking for dtypes in pandas is done with the `Series.dtype` method, not type

Comment: I'm not really an expert in Pandas, but... what about `label.fit_transform(float(balanced_data['activity']))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is somewhere else. You define `label = LabelEncoder()`  - then you use `label.type` and get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'type'`.

This means `label` (at this exact moment) is of type string whereas it should be reported to be `<class 'sklearn.preprocessing._label.LabelEncoder'>` following `label = LabelEncoder()`!

---

When fit'ing labels that way, you get integers already, not strings: no conversion whatsoever needed:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd
from random import random, choice

r = random
c = choice

df = pd.DataFrame([[r(),r(),r(),r(),c(["sitting","standing"])] for _ in range(6)],
                  columns=["quat1","quat2","quat3","quat4","activity"])

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df["label"] = le.fit_transform(df["activity"])

print(df)
print(df["label"].dtypes)
```

Output:

```
      quat1     quat2     quat3     quat4  activity  label
0  0.550365  0.051738  0.485262  0.194497  standing      1
1  0.656460  0.151324  0.131370  0.338022  standing      1
2  0.512595  0.501235  0.449589  0.302794  standing      1
3  0.440568  0.043643  0.817394  0.128534   sitting      0
4  0.364890  0.714289  0.683436  0.731021   sitting      0
5  0.708488  0.423278  0.624220  0.880735  standing      1

int32
```

To get back to your label, use

```
print(le.inverse_transform([0]))   # ['sitting']
```

See [Examples on `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder` documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let’s assume a new DataFrame with two columns (the Product and Price columns). Only this time, the values under the Price column would contain a combination of both numeric and non-numeric data:
You can then use the astype(float) method to perform the conversion into a float:

```
Data = {'Product': ['A','B'],'Price': ['250','270']}
df = pd.DataFrame(Data)
df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(float)

print (df)
print (df.dtypes)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the "eval"

```
st = "5"
st_as_int = eval(st) 
print(type(st_as_int))
```

would return "int"

Comment: eval works for just one object, I want to change all the column of the Dataframe

Comment: Yes so:
balanced_data['label'] = balanced_data['label'].apply(lambda x: eval(x))

Answer (score -1):

Since the label is currently a string, you will have to cast the string to a `float`.

```
label = float(label)
```

That should work. [More on casting here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float)